# What is the right way to do this HTML: header with icon linked

Tags: html

I know how to make these examples look and behave the same. But I would like to know which is the *right* way to build a HTML structure.

1. `<a><img><h1></h1></a>` - looks wrong because an inline element is inside of a block element
2. `<a><img></a><h1><a></a></h1>` - the same `a`-element is defined twice. Also I'm not sure about markup inside headers
3. Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Markup (1) is valid according to HTML5 drafts (and accepted by browsers) but not by current HTML specifications. Markup (2) violates usability and accessibility principles if the two links point to the same destination. The following markup is natural and makes only the image and the heading text clickable (not the entire `h1` element which occupies the available width by default):

```
<h1><a href=...><img src=... alt=...>Heading text</a></h1>
```

Links have always been allowed inside headings, but not vice versa.

On the other hand, there is seldom a good reason to make a heading clickable, and I wonder why the image is there. If you mean that this should really be a *header*, an overall site header, and not a *heading*, and if the image is actually a company logo or, then appropriate markup would rather be something like

```
<div class=header><a href="/"><img alt=ACME src=acme-logo.png> – American Company
Manufacturing Everything</a></div>
```

(reserving `h1` for the overall *page* heading).

Comment: There's a few good reasons to make the heading (text) clickable (ie. linking back to the same page)... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23917/why-on-stackexchange-sites-is-the-post-title-on-the-question-page-a-link-to-it/23926